# Lua on boolean change event?

Tags: events, lua, boolean, onchange

So I was brainstorming something about programming, basically a logic emulator in lua. I have to overhaul the whole system, but I thought that event based actions could be better than constant update actions.

I have something like:

```
local var1 = false
local var2 = false
while true do
  if key == "a" then
    var1 = not var1
  end
  if key == "s" then var2 = not var2 end
  var2 = var1
end
```

But i want something like this:

```
local var1 = false
local var2 = false
while true do
  if key == "a" then
    var1 = not var1
  end
  if key == "s" then var2 = not var2 end
  if on.change(var1) then
    var2 = var1
  end
end
```

So yeah, I want var2 to be independent, I don't want it to keep setting itself as var1, I only want var2 to react to var1, if var1 has changed.

If we look at the first code chunk, you see I cant really control var2 independently, It will always set itself to var1, it might set itself to var1 for a really short period of time.

If we look at the second code chunk, you can see that I can control var2 independently from var1, and have it still react to var1.

Now the most analogous thing to do would be to do something like this:

```
local var1 = false
local var2 = false
while true do
  if key == "a" then
    var1 = not var1
    var2 = var1
  end
  if key == "s" then
    var2 = not var2
  end
end
```

But I'm afraid that this wouldn't be really possible to implement, and it would slow it down, since the are a lot of loops going, adding more nested loops would really slow it down...

So please post something that is similar to the event on the second code chunk, I already posted the analogous one, but it would be hard to implement, and there would be serious side effects, like nested loops for what I'm doing.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: And the reason it would be hard to implement because it has to look at another variable, and that it should work **without** the key presses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do stuff like that with metatables (pseudocode):

```
local mt = { __index = function(i,v)
    if i == "var1" then 
        var1 = v
        var2 = v
    end
end }

_G.setmetatable(mt)
```

But I'd recommend you google enough for some library that would do that automatically.

Comment: Also I haven't found any library, I have searched for lua event handler or lua events or even lua on change event. I'll try to understand this code, the underscores make it that much harder...

Comment: @EEVV there are literally two underscores that denote the metatable `__index` field. (And one in the global context value `_G`) Go back to your Lua book.

Comment: no, im self taught lua, i just messed around with the code. I have heard that underscores means that it is private. But then again local and private seem so similar. I would rather have it be java like or c like where you write the access private, local, global etc..

Comment: @EEVV Then stop being self-taught and read *Programming in Lua*. Whatever you've heard is just wrong.